# TF resolve doesn't understand server item specs, only local ones

Tags: version-control, command-line

I have a workspace with 2 folders - one with a file that won't auto-resolve. I want to run `tf resolve` only on the other folder. But, it only works using local item specs, not server:

```
D:\Project > tf resolve /noprompt /auto:AutoMerge /recursive
D:\Project\BadFolder\UnresolvableFile.xml: The source and target both have changes.
D:\Project\BadFolder\UnresolvableFile.xml: 1964 local, 1263 server, 0 both, and 346 conflicting
                                          <<<<<<<<<<<< Expected behavior

D:\Project > tf resolve /noprompt /auto:AutoMerge /recursive D:\Project\GoodFolder
There are no conflicts to resolve.        <<<<<<<<<<<< This is the behavior I want

D:\Project > tf resolve /noprompt /auto:AutoMerge /recursive $/Project/GoodFolder
D:\Project\BadFolder\UnresolvableFile.xml: The source and target both have changes.
D:\Project\BadFolder\UnresolvableFile.xml: 1964 local, 1263 server, 0 both, and 346 conflicting
                                          <<<<<<<<<<<< WTH, it's exactly the same like above!
```

My Workspace mappings appear correct:

```
D:\Project > tf workfold
===================================================================
Workspace : (...)
Collection: (...)http://vstfps:8080/tfs/protection
 $/Project: D:\Project
```

I can change my script to use local folders, but that's hardly desirable. Is there a way to use server paths in `tf resolve`?

Comment: What type of file is the unresolvable file?

Comment: It's an xml, updated question accordingly.